# How do you make the spicy meat recipe?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I found the Old Man's diary in the house near the cooking pot.

There's a recipe which will give you cold resistance. He says it uses **raw meat**, a **spicy pepper** and some other ingredient he can't remember.

What is the third ingredient?

---

OK, so I looked up the answer.

> A **Hyrule Bass** caught in the lake West of the Temple of Time is what you need.

**My question now is:** How would I have known that on my own? I only found 3 peppers so I wouldn't have been able to experiment much with the ingredients I had. And it's unlikely I would've found that any time soon.

Is there any other hint that points you toward the third ingredient?

Comment: There's no hard rule for what makes what. Most meals are generic sounding that you're given a lot of leeway when it comes to cooking a particular meal.  For the most part, you don't need to worry about the exact items that you mix in or the dish it creates, just that the items have the effects you're looking for in your dish.  Of course, you'll have to know the difference between food items and elixir items and try not to mix the two, as those tend to produce unexpected results. Otherwise if you're following a specific recipe for a quest, then follow the recipe.

Comment: If you just want the cold resistance, you don't actually need the meat or the fish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read his diary, it mentions that the name of the dish is spicy meat and seafood fry. That's the clue that the last ingredient is fish.

Also, you don't have to specifically use raw meat. I was able to make it with raw drumsticks instead, which is a lot easier to get. I think it just has to have something spicy, some kind of meat, and some kind of fish, all of which is pretty obvious from the name of the dish.

Answer (score 7):

I mean, the dish is called "Spicy Meat and Fish"; it stands to reason that the ingredients will be meat and fish.

Answer (score 1):

Which Spicy Meat recipe?

Spicy Meat and Mushroom Skewer is:

- Acorn
- Sunshroom
- Raw Bird Drumstick

Spicy Meat and Seafood Fry is:

- Hyrule Bass
- Raw Meat
- Spicy Pepper

I got this information from this [recipe guide](http://gamehalp.com/legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-recipes/8).